# Complexity of generating all subsets of size $k$ using recursion

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, recursion

What is the complexity of the following (Python) code, that builds the list L of all subsets of size $k$ of a given set?

```python
# arr: input array
# k  : size of subsets
# tmp : current subset
# idx : current index in tmp
# i : current array element
# L : list of all subsets of size k
def subsets(arr, k, idx, tmp, i, L = []):

    if(idx == k):
        L.append(tmp.copy())
        return 
 
    # When no more elements are there to put in tmp[]
    if(i >= len(arr)):
        return
 
    # current is included, put next at next location
    tmp[idx] = arr[i]
    subsets(arr, k, idx + 1, tmp, i + 1, L)
     
    # current is excluded, replace it with next
    # (i+1 is passed, but index is not changed)
    subsets(arr, k, idx, tmp, i + 1, L)

    return L
 
# Driver Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    r = 3
    print(subsets(arr, r, 0, [0]*r, 0))
```

Intuitively, the algorithm generates all the $\binom{n}{k} = O(n^k)$ such subsets ; but how to compute the complexity of this algorithm "rigorously" and not "intuitively"?

Comment: Do you hear about __[master theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))__

Comment: Yes, but Master Theorem applies on *Divide and Conquer* recursions, on the form $T(n) = a.T(n/b) + f(n)$. The recursion above is not of this form.

Comment: The usual method to evaluate the complexity of recursive algorithms is by establishing a recurrent equation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thx Yves, since my post, I indeed found information on solving those equations by the method of the characteristic equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime of a recursive function can be expressed as a recurrence relation in terms of the sizes of its input parameters. Your recurrence begins with $idx=0$ and has a base case (stopping condition) of when $idx=k$. The quantity $k-idx$ starts high and the recursion stops when $k-idx$ reaches $0$.

So let $T(n)$ represent the runtime of your function on a difference of $n=k-idx$. It makes two recursive calls, both with the same $k$ and both with $idx+1$. So the difference $k-idx$ reduces by $1$ every recursion. And every recursive iteration makes two recursive calls. So we have $T(n) = 2T(n-1)+c$ where $c$ is the amount of steps used in each call frame (that is, $c$ counts the number of comparisons made for your base cases and the set-up of two new call frames and the return statement).

Now just solve $T(n) = 2T(n-1)+c$ subject to your base case (when $n = k-idx = 0$ it does 1 or 2 steps, whichever you are counting). So the base case of the recursion is $T(0) = 1$ (or $2$).

Both of these base cases result in solving the recurrence to $T(n)=O(2^n)$.

Note that your algorithm here is essentially producing all subsets (which is an $\Theta(2^n)$ process) and you are only keeping the ones that have $k$ items. So this implementation is doing more work than necessary. As an example, if you are finding all the 3-sets of an initial set of $[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]$ in order to get to $[8,9,10]$ you consider all the cases of $1$ being chosen or not, $2$ being chosen or not, $3$ being chosen or not, $4$ being chosen or not, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You know how many results are produced. If you can determine how many operations each result takes, then you just multiply.

Comment: That's essentially my question! :)